# Is it possible to create a web Application using Xamarin? And then Create Xamarin iPhone and Android to connect to it?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I want to create an application using Xamarin. This is a web Server and client iPhone and Android. I would like to know Can I make my core web Application Using Xamarin.

Sorry, I do not have any Experience in Xamarin. Then, I want to connect this Web Server Xamarin App to an iPhone and Android App.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

At the core, Xamarin's iOS and Android Technology is based on [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) which in turn implements most of the parts of Microsoft's .Net Stack. So the answer is yes, you could build your backend using .Net with either Microsoft's or Mono's ASP.Net Stacks and have your Xamarin Mobile apps connect to it.

Comment: Noted, Thanks. Could you please provide me some links as a guide. Actually I have worked with Php, and Objective-C. I do not have much experience on Asp.net. Thanks!

Comment: would be nice for me as well.... how can i add a WebApplication to my Xamarin project?